# Bash split an array, add a variable and concatenate it back together

Tags: linux, bash

I've been trying to figure this out, unfortunately I can't.  I am trying to create a function that finds the ';' character, puts four spaces before it and then and puts the code back together in a neat sentence.  I've been cracking at this for a bit, and can't figure out a couple of things.  I can't get the output to display what I want it to.  I've tried finding the index of the ';' character and it seems I'm going about it the wrong way.  The other mistake that I seem to be making is that I'm trying to split in a array in a for loop, and then split the individual words in the array by letter but I can't figure out how to do that either.  If someone can give me a pointer this would be greatly appreciated. This is in bash version 4.3.48

```
#!commentPlacer() 
{

arg=($1)   #argument
len=${#arg[@]}    #length of the argument
comment=;    #character to look for in second loop
commaIndex=(${arg[@]#;})   #the attempted index look up
commentSpace="    ;"    #the variable being concatenated into the array

for(( count1=0; count1 <= ${#arg[@]}; count1++ ))  #search the argument looking for comment space
do  if [[  ${arg[count1]} != commentSpace ]]  #if no commentSpace variable then
      then  for (( count2=0; count2 < ${#arg[count1]} ; count2++ ))    #loop through again
                do if [[ ${arg[count2]} != comment  ]]  #if no comment
                    then A=(${arg[@]:0:commaIndex})
                    A+=(commentSpace)
                    A+=(${arg[@]commaIndex:-1})  #concatenate array
                    echo "$A"
                fi
        done
    fi
done

}
```

Comment: Btw.: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I did sorry about that.

Comment: Why don't you use `sed`? `echo $1 | sed '/;/    ;/g'`

Comment: *＋1* for asking a Bash question that has to do with programming and development, and includes program control flow (and not just how to run a command).

Comment: @jww thanks for the compliment.  This has been a about 15 lessons in one.  Tough going but been a pleasure to learn bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, it's basically to put 4 spaces in front of each ";" in the argument, and print the result. This is actually simple to do in bash with a string substitution:

```
commentPlacer() {
    echo "${1//;/    ;}"
}
```

The expansion here has the format `${variable//pattern/replacement}`, and it gives the contents of the variable, with each occurrence of `pattern` replaced by `replacement`. Note that with only a single `/` before the pattern, it would replace only the first occurrence.

Now, I'm not sure I understand how your script is supposed to work, but I see several things that clearly aren't doing what you expect them to do. Here's a quick summary of the problems I see:

```
arg=($1)   #argument
```

This doesn't create an array of characters from the first argument. `var=(...)` treats the thing in `( )` as a list of *words*, not characters. Since `$1` isn't in double-quotes, it'll be split into words based on whitespace (generally spaces, tabs, and linefeeds), and then any of those words that contain wildcards will be expanded to a list of matching filenames. I'm pretty sure this isn't at all what you want (in fact, it's almost never what you want, so variable references should almost always be double-quoted to prevent it). Creating a character array in bash isn't easy, and in general isn't something you want to do. You can access individual characters in a string variable with `${var:index:1}`, where `index` is the character you want (counting from 0).

```
 commaIndex=(${arg[@]#;})   #the attempted index look up
```

This doesn't do a lookup. The substitution `${var#pattern}` gives the value of `var` with `pattern` removed from the front (if it matches). If there are multiple possible matches, it uses the shortest one. The variant `${var##pattern}` uses the longest possible match. With `${array[@]#pattern}`, it'll try to remove the pattern from each element -- and since it's not in double-quotes, the result of that gets word-split and wildcard-expanded as usual. I'm pretty sure this isn't at all what you want.

```
if [[  ${arg[count1]} != commentSpace ]]  #if no commentSpace variable then
```

Here (and in a number of other places), you're using a variable without `$` in front; this doesn't use the variable at all, it just treats "commentSpace" as a static string. Also, in several places it's important to have double-quotes around it, e.g. to keep the spaces in `$commentSpace` from vanishing due to word splitting. There are some places where it's safe to leave the double-quotes off, but in general it's too hard to keep track of them, so just use double-quotes everywhere.

General suggestions: don't try to write c (or java or whatever) programs in bash; it works too differently, and you have to think differently. Use [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) to spot common problems (like non-double-quoted variable references). Finally, you can see what bash is doing by putting `set -x` before a section that doesn't do what you expect; that'll make bash print each line as it executes it, showing the equivalent of what it's executing.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.  I'm glad you took the time to help me learn from the many mistakes I made in bash.  You put a lot of effort into this explanation which is exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

Make a little function using *pattern substitution* on stdin:

```
semicolon4s() { while read x; do echo "${x//;/    ;}"; done; }
semicolon4s <<< 'foo;bar;baz'
```

Output:

```
foo    ;bar    ;baz
```